# io.smallrye.config.ConfigValidationException: Configuration validation failed

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, quarkus

Currently, the Quarkus guides say that in order to enable SSL when communicating with a Kafka broker you should set

```
quarkus.kafka-streams.security.protocol=SSL
```

However, doing this results in the error:

```
io.smallrye.config.ConfigValidationException: Configuration validation failed:
quarkus.kafka-streams.security.protocol does not map to any root
```

Answer (score 0):

The current documentation, (and IntelliJ auto-complete) is incorrect. The correct property should be

```
kafka-streams.security.protocol=SSL
```

Comment: Which part of the documentation mentions the incorrect property?